# How to remove "'[[]]" in side string by python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string: `[[word]]`.
I just need `word` of this.

Currently, I am using the following regular expression:

```
re.sub(r'[^[....]', "", )
```

But it does not work. What's the correct regular expression?

Comment: What is the error? And what is the exact code you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a regex, you can use [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> **str.strip(*[chars]*)**
>   - Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The `chars` argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or `None`, the `chars` argument defaults to removing whitespace. The `chars` argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

```
s = "[[word]]";
print(s.strip('[]'))
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/8rHTbX)

If you want to strip `[[` and `]]` [with a regex](https://ideone.com/EeTzqP):

```
print(re.sub(r"^\[{2}|\]{2}$", "", s))
```

Comment: I think my suggestion is a bit more flexible than `.replace('[[','').replace(']]','')`. You can further adapt the leading and trailing characters to remove either with `strip` or with the regex (the regex is a bit costly in terms of performance, but can offer better control over the trimming process).

Comment: hej, sorry that distrub you, here i got one more question: input: u'\\word\\with'   if i want to get back: u'\word\with', what should i do with it

Comment: Do you mean `ur'\\word\\with'` and you want to get `\word\with` as ouput in the console? Like [this](https://ideone.com/EiTwDM)?

Comment: @ stribizhev, what i want for input is : u'\\word\\with'   and get back is: u'\word\with'

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Please check [this fiddle](https://ideone.com/5ruGoY) and [another fiddle](https://ideone.com/Cah4OZ). If it is not what you need, please update that fiddle with the input you need.

Comment: i got list: [hello world good boy]     and now need get the  'hello' back, what should do for it

Comment: No idea, please try something and then post a new question in case of failure. Here is a hint: if it is a single word after initial `[` in a string, you need no regex, just trim the string the same way as in this question, and then use `split` to get the first word (it will be the first element in the resulting array).

Comment: I see, Thanks for the time~~

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `[`, because it's have a special meaning in regular expression. You can escape them with `\`:

Use this regular expression:

```
\[\[(\w+)\]\]
```

`\w` will match any word-character and the `+`-sign matches multiple of them, at least one.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `strip`, it removes given characters from the begining and the end of the string:

```
a = '[[word]]'
b = a.strip('[]')
```

There are also `lstrip` and `rstrip` to remove given characters from left or right side of the string respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want use regex? It is enough `string.replace()`

```
>>> a = '[[word]]'
>>> b = a.replace('[[','').replace(']]','')
>>> b
'word'
```

Comment: This will replace `[[` and `]]` even if they are inside the word. Hopefully, that will not take place.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always in this structure, you could do

```
s = '[[word]]'
print(s[2:-2]) # word
```